# I have a problem left clicking the x,y, z axis

Tags: objects

I can't get my objects... which at the moment is the cube to move along the x,y, z axis using my mouse. If I left click, all I seem to do is move the crosshairs.   I am using Blender 2.72.  The only way I can move along those axis' is if I click "G" for grab then which ever I would like either x,y, or z.  if I try to get the trackball to move... I cant do anything with it.  IS this a bug?  Ive been looking for answers on youtube in tutorals but, everyone just left clicks and moves along the choice axis... I feel like im lost until I can get this working.   HELP!

Comment: Left click only sets the 3D cursor, what you probably want is to select an object by right clicking, 'G' followed by either 'X','Y','Z' to constrain movement to the selected axis. See also http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Grab

Comment: well thats the only way for me to slide along the axis but, just clicking/holding down  on the arrows doesnt work.  iThis is fine if I am only sliding straight down the axis.  but, if I use the rotate manipulater where I want to rotate the x,y,or z  mouse buttons dont do a thing.